# Excel API query using cell value

Tags: excel, api, excel-formula, ms-office

I am new to Excel, and I have tried to do little research on this but couldnt find anything. I would really appropriate if someone could give me some tips or resources that I could find the answer at. 
So here is the problem. Lets say I have a excel sheet with the following values:

```
start_date     2016-07-01
end_date       2016-08-08
```

And also I want to use an API, that structured in a following way...
`xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx&start_date&to&end_date` (for example).

How can I use the values from the excel sheet into the API query, in a way I want to be able to update the dates in the sheet and get updated API return dataset.
Is is possible?

Comment: I don't understand the question. So you have a sheet, with data, If you want to call an API, first what is the user interaction that triggers the API? What would you do with the result?

Yes a lot of stuff is possible with Excel. It amazes me how much you cna do if you use the right tools so you are on the right track.
1. You can simply use the VBA macros
2. You can use VBA full powered Excel macro enabled worksheet 
3. You can use .NET/C#/VB.NET 
4. You can add ribbons/controls etc.
So please post more details about what you want, how the functionality gets triggered, etc.

Comment: I am really sorry if I did confuse you. So the API query returns a historic dataset, I cant post the actual API due to some privacy issues. So, technically i want to have user input from excel sheet. For example in python I would, save it as a str value, and + to the actual API sting and call it. So what I want to do is, call an API query in excel, which will have values from excel sheet cell. Lets say,  2016-07-01 this is the date that I want to call my API with, and when i put the date into a curtain cell in Excel i want my API to use this value, concentrate  into the API link.

Comment: I am assuming this is a webAPI. To call a webAPI, you need to use some VBA or use B.B.net or c#. Getting the API URL is not the issue. You need to figure out how to call from via.